# CodeIgniter Menu bar problems

Tags: codeigniter

This is my menu. I fetch this menu items from database. Now, If I click on any menu items, then it goes to his page. But the menu bar is missing. I am showing my menus in `master_page.php` in view folder.

Now I want, this menu bar will be fixed in any page. So, I need to include or load the `master_page.php` file in the menu items pages? But I don't know the procedure. Please, someone help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

No. Don't use the `include`tag. Use as simple in controller

**Explain** :
If you need to load the navigation just call the view in each and every controller

```
$this->load->view("master_page")
```

Example:

```
$this->load->view("head")
$this->load->view("master_page")
$this->load->view("body")
$this->load->view("foot")
```

**Importent**:
Keep the order of page load.

- head
- navigation
- body
- foot

Comment: i wrote this like : $this->load->view('master_page'); , but it gets 2 errors. 1 is :

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: all_menu
Filename: views/master_page.php
Line Number: 16
And the line number 16 is: foreach ($all_menu as $v_menu) , its a loop by which im fetching menus from database.

Comment: problem solved. actually how first time i fetch this menus from database, the same few lines sould be written in all controller.Thanks

Comment: :) , can you please tell me the right way to ask questions here?  i faced problems here.Some one make it change.1. look in my question, 'master_page' the file name is shaded? how can i do this? 2. i added a image link, but here, the screen shot is here, how can i add screen shot here?

Comment: @RubelDinira If this help please **[ACCEPT** it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)